# Working with MongoDB using Apache Gora 0.6 configuration

Tags: java, mongodb, nutch, gora

I'm using MongoDB as Gora backend for my nutch implementation. I have a need to delete some documents from MongoDB. Instead of writing custom class based on Java and MongoDB, I'm trying to see if already existing Gora APIs can be used to do this work. Tried a lot but not much information available. Please let me know your thoughts and any pointers in achieving the same. Mostly [this](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?source_dir=gora-master/gora-mongodb/src/main/java/org/apache/gora/mongodb/store/MongoStoreParameters.java) URL has come to rescue however its not helping to full extent. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use MongoStore.detele method. It takes id as a parameter and return a boolean value. [method url](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?source_dir=gora-master/gora-mongodb/src/main/java/org/apache/gora/mongodb/store/MongoStore.java)

Comment: First we need to do initialize() to get mongoClientColl, right? What could be the value of first two fields in initialize()?

Comment: initialize() function will take 3 parameters keyClass, Persistance class, and property file